# Sending object data from ios application to server application

Tags: iphone, networking

I am looking for a little bit of guidence here. I know that this question is a little vauge, but im hoping someone can point me into the right direction. I would like to send the state of a user interface slider in an ios application to 
an external java application. My problem is that I am not sure what to use in order to do so. Is this something that can be done with NSOutputStream and a SliderDidChange method, or does this require something more? My goal of this post is to be pointed in the direction of a good article or book chapter I can read about the subject. I am familiar with sending and recieving list data using XMLParser but that does not seem to be a fit here. Thank you for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Send the data as payload of an post request using NSURLRequest

Comment: Thank you for your very simple yet very helpful answer! I will use NSURLRequest when I get home today.